# How to right fold using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, fold

Using LINQ, we can perform a [left fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_on_lists) on a list via `Aggregate`:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var value = numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a - b); // ((1 - 2) - 3) - 4 == -8
```

Is there a similar way using LINQ to perform a right fold?

```
var value = numbers.Aggregate(???); // 1 - (2 - (3 - 4)) == -2
```

Comment: You can revercse and aggregate after that. `numbers.Reverse().Aggregate((a, b) => a - b);`

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I googled this post's title and nothing (prominently) showed up, so I figured I would share my solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right folding is essentially folding from right to left. We can replicate a right fold, if we `Reverse` the enumerable first, then perform a left fold via `Aggregate`:

```
var value = numbers.Reverse().Aggregate((a, b) => a - b);
```

---

As an extension method:

```
public static TSource RightFold<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func)
{
    return source.Reverse().Aggregate(func);
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = numbers.RightFold((a, b) => a - b); // ((4 - 3) - 2) - 1 == -2
// 1 - (2 - (3 - 4)) == ((4 - 3) - 2) - 1
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, try it with 3 arguments: your function gives `(3 - 2) - 1 == 0 `, but OP was looking for `1 - (2 - 3) == 2`. You need to switch the order of the arguments to `func`: `return source.Reverse().Aggregate((a, b) => func(b, a));`

Answer (score 1):

In case you already using [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) check `AggregateRight` method